# Do powers 'explode' when re-used?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have upgraded 'Singularity' and 'Defense Drone' to explode when they expire/get destroyed. Often times, the power gets recharged before even the previous instances self destruct.

So if I cast these before they self destruct, will those previous instances 'explode', or did I just lose out on the damage caused by the explosion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you recast them, they do no explode. If they did, they would be the highest dps powers in the game in addition to their other benefits..

Comment: Thanks... but what is DPS? Also, I've heard EMS somewhere - could you please tell what that is?

Comment: @adityamenon DPS means damage per second.   A fairly common term that can apply to most video games.  Not sure about EMS though.